# What is cache tag directory?

Tags: caching, operating-system

I am studying Operating Systems and I am stuck on this term "Tag Directory". 
What is tag directory exactly? Where is it present? What is its role?

I am a little confused. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

In the memory organisation of caches, there are two blocks - one block is reserved for storing tags associated with each line of cache, and the other block is reserved for storing the cached data.

The following figure shows memory organisation in direct mapped cache.

[image: Cache storage in direct mapped cache]

Usually, a "cache block" refers to the block that stores the cached data and "tag directory" refers to the block that stores the tags associated with each cahe line.

Size of tag directory =
(number of bits to represent 1 tag) × (number of cache lines)
= tag bits × (cache size / line size)

Note: line size of cache = block size of main memory

Answer (score -1):

Tag directory is used to search data in distributed last level caches.
If the requested data is not found in any caches, a memory address is sent from the tag directory to the memory controller

Comment: That is the definintion of a tag + a cache. It has nothing to do with a tag directory. Tag is used to search data in caches. Not "tag directory". And the second line "if requested data... memory controller" that is how the cache works. Again, nothing to do with "tag directory".

Answer (score -1):

Tag directory is the entire tag block which consists of mapping with the cache lines.

For example in your cache if you have 10 cache lines (in other words your cache can store 10 blocks of memory simultaneously). Then you have a total of 12 tags.

This is because each cache line would be tied to a particular tag. Tag refers to a larger region of memory.

So you have 12 tags. And if you want to find out how much total space these 10 tags take up in the memory then find out how much each tag takes up.

Let's say 1 tag = 4 bits.

Then the total tag directory size = 12 tags X 4 bits = 48 bits

But we know 1 byte = 8 bits. Hence, tag directory size = 48/8 = 6bytes

That means that in this case the entire block of memory that is storing the 10 tags will take up 6bytes of space (not taking into account OS storage complexity).

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain why would a 10 cache lines have 12 tags